# How i can track Safari activity from my application

Tags: cocoa, safari, webkit

I have to develop an application to monitor Safari activity like all open url , tabs on particular window and loding time of particular url.

I also need to track online streaming that is happening on particular opened htmm page

URL of streaming source, which player is being used for streaming and all other basic information which opened page contains.

Answer (score 0):

> I have to develop an application to monitor Safari activity like all open url , tabs on particular window and loding time of particular url.

You can ask Safari for the first two things via AppleScript; the latter is in the Element Inspector, but I'm not sure why you would want it in another application.

> I also need to track online streaming that is happening on particular opened htmm page

That's a separate question, so you should post it separately.